# Finding all files that have whitespace in last few lines

Tags: linux, whitespace

I am attempting to search all the files in a website for any whitespace that is in the last 5 lines of each files and want the terminal to return a list of any files that meet that criteria.

The reason for this is that we have problems on a Drupal site where whitespace is being injected into images which causes them to become corrupt and won't show.

I've tried a few things below, none of which give me the desired results although I believe that I am quite close to getting the right command.

I've scoured the internet and stackexchange and found some answers that I believed would work but sadly not for me.

Attempt #1

```
find . -name "*.php" | xargs grep -c -P '\s+$' | grep -v ':0$'
```

At first, this appeared to work in listing all files with a whitespace but I found it wasn't specific enough and gave a list of around 500 files, not all of which ended in a whitespace. I started to plod through them but then realised it was not giving me a list of *all* the files that had whitespaces in so found another method.

Attempt #2

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'grep -q  " +$" < <(tail -n 5 "$1")' _ {} \; -printf '%p\n'
```

All this listed was two JS files which wasn't very helpful.

Attempt #3

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'grep -q " +$" < <(tail -n 5 "$1") && printf '%\n' "$1"' _ {} \;
```

Again, this returned the same two JS files.

Comment: Your last 2 attempts don't specify the `-name "*.php"` option - is this intentional?

Comment: Sort of intentional! I figured it wouldn't make much of a difference and I could just exclude the non-PHP files in the results. I wanted to simplify the command a little.

Comment: Perhaps I'm reading the wrong, but if "whitespace is being injected into **images** which causes them to become corrupt and won't show" why are you checking php files at all? Wouldn't you just need to check the various types of _image_ files?

Comment: The whitespace is being inject into the image uploads BY one of the PHP files. That's what whitespace can do after a closing PHP tag at the end of a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the `+` inside grep expression, ex. see [gnu grpe manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/grep-regular-expression-syntax.html).

Using `< <(...)` shell redirection with process substitution is unneeded here, just pipe it `|`.

The following works. Notice how I needed to double escape `\\+`, because `\\` is expanded to `\` inside `"` braces.:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'tail -n 5 "$1" | grep -q " \\+$" && printf "%s\n" "$1"' -- {} \;
```

However when using `xargs` you can do it in parallel `-P0`, also I like the debugging with `-t` better. For strange filenames add `-print0` and `-0` options to `find` and `xargs`.

```
find . -type f | xargs -n1 sh -c 'tail -n 5 "$1" | grep -q " \\+$" && printf "%s\n" "$1"' --
```

Comment: This appears to work quite nicely, I'll go through the files that it's come back with then accept your answer provided it does 100% work :)

Answer (score 2):

You where almost there

```
grep -q  " +$"
```

won't work because the modifier `+` is part of the extended regular expressions, and grep works by default with the basic/POSIX regular expressions (where the `+`-sign is interpreted as a literal character).

There are two solutions:

1. Switch to extended regex using the flag `-E`: `grep -qE " +$"` 
   or by adding the backslash before the `+` sign: `grep -q " \+$"`
2. But because (in my experience) extended regexes are slower in Unix than the basic ones, and you want to find files with 'one or more spaces at the end': grepping on 'one space at the end' will also list the appropiate files: thus `grep -q  " $"`

Comment: No, it does, just you have to escape it `grep ' \+$'`

Comment: @KamilCuk - I did not know that. Thanx, like learning new stuff :) I will update my answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's a shame I can only accept one!